# Angular Dynamic Meta Description

Tags: angularjs, seo

Current Issue and Status : As Angular is a single page app I get  The same title and description on my indexed pages on google
Objective: Improving SEO  I require  Dynamic Title and Meta Descriptions when I route to my pages

Goal:   Need help implementing : https://github.com/moonfuse/angular-meta

1. I call the module

2. I dependency inject the module
             angular.module("myApp", ["customFilters", "meta"])
             .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, MetaProvider)

   I add title and description to my to my routing   note   MetaProvider should work the same way          as $routeProvider

   ```
    $routeProvider.when("/myedition", {

            templateUrl: "/views/myedition.html"

                  });

                   MetaProvider.when("/myedition", {
                           title: "Your Collection",
                           description: "Publish Your Own Collection"
                       })
   ```

HTML  of myedition

```
  <title data-ng-bind="meta.title"></title>
   <meta name="description" content="{{meta.description}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll also need to include a Meta.init() in a run block of your app.js file.

```
app.run(['Meta', function(Meta){
    Meta.init();
}]);
```

Just missed this step myself and its working now that I've added it, let me know if that doesn't work out for you.